# Excel concatenate fill down won't advance by 6 the way I need it to

Tags: excel, concatenation, fill

I have an excel worksheet that has formulas and references other tabs in the workbook.

I'm pulling a street number and street name and putting it in another tab.

Here are 2 lines of formula:

```
=CONCATENATE('Building Limits'!C669," - ",'Building Limits'!C672," ",'Building Limits'!D672)

=CONCATENATE('Building Limits'!C675," - ",'Building Limits'!C678," ",'Building Limits'!D678)
```

I have tried to fill down, copy & paste special and this is what I get:

```
=CONCATENATE('Building Limits'!C676," - ",'Building Limits'!C679," ",'Building Limits'!D679)
```

I need the line below to advance to `C681` and `C684`.

I know I can copy down and adjust each line, but I do not have to the time to do it all manually. I have to add 140 more lines to get my sheet to correctly reference the addresses that I've already entered.

I didn't create the workbook, so it's more than a little challenging.
Can anybody offer up a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX():

```
=CONCATENATE(INDEX('Building Limits'!C:C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*6 + 669)," - ",INDEX('Building Limits'!C:C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*6 + 672)," ",INDEX('Building Limits'!D:D,(ROW(1:1)-1)*6 + 672))
```

`6` is the spacing and the `+ 669` and `+ 672` are the starting rows.